# Iterate Over objects in an m2m_changed signal

Tags: python, django, signal-processing, django-signals, manytomanyfield

I have the following setup:
order/models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_deliverer = models.ManyToManyField(Deliverer, related_name='deliverer')
    deliveringstatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

order/signals.py

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Order.deliverer.through)
def m2m_changed_order_deliverer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['action'] == 'post_add':
        instance.deliveringstatus = True
        instance.save()

#changes the order model's, on-delivery status to TRUE once an order_deliverer has been appended onto its ManyToManyField.
```

account/models.py

```
class Deliverer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='deliverer')
    busy = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Order.order_deliverer.through)
def m2m_changed_deliverer_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['action'] == 'post_add':
        #print(instance.order_deliverer.through.objects.all())
        obj = instance.order_deliverer.through.objects.last().deliverer
        obj.busy = True
        obj.save()
#alters the deliverer's profile status to busy.
```

**1. My problem is on handling iterations. If the order's order_deliverer field has multiple user objects, the account signal is only handled on the last object.**

**2. How do I iterate & alter each deliverer's profile.**

I'm thinking of looping via 'for' but I first need to be able to fetch individual user objects rather than first or last.

Comment: Please share your models as well.

Comment: any idea on this?